# How to debug with xvfb-run wrapped in the vscode?

Tags: vscode-debugger, xvfb

I want to debug `rl_methods.py` with `xvfb-run` wrapped, just as input the command

```
xvfb-run -a -s "-screen 0 640x480x24" python rl_methods.py
```

in the terminal.
How should I modify `launch.json` to achieve this.